# Java: "INCOMPATIBLE TYPE" error

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I am working in Android Studio and trying to compile some existing code, but I get an "incompatible type" (object required) error for variable `BluetoothDevice`
at this line, though I have the import line at the top of the code:

```
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;

/* other code */

for(BluetoothDevice bt : pairedDevices)
```

Here is the function with the line of interest:

```
public void pairedDevicesList() {
    pairedDevices = myBluetooth.getBondedDevices();
    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

    if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
        for(BluetoothDevice bt : pairedDevices) {
            list.add(bt.getName() + "\n" + bt.getAddress()); //Get the device's name and the address}
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Paired Bluetooth Devices Found.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    final ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
    devicelist.setAdapter(adapter);
    devicelist.setOnItemClickListener(myListClickListener); //Method called when the device from the list is clicked
}
```

Any ideas?  Thanks

Comment: I'm pretty sure `pairedDevices` is a raw type like your `ArrayList list = new ArrayList()`. So ... read why they shouldn't be that.

Comment: Can you include the declaration for `pairedDevices`?

Comment: Thanks everyone... it turns out I needed these two lines prior to that "for" statement...     BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = bluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();